# Laptop not turning on and battery indicator led is blinking white

Tags: boot, laptop-display, led, blank-screen

From some months, I have been facing trouble in starting up the laptop (ASUS VivoBook 14 Ryzen 4500U). When I turn my laptop on the battery indicator blinks white (even when plugged in). I can tell that the grub menu comes on starting but there is no display. If Ubuntu opens then there is a flash on screen and then black screen. And if Windows opens, there is no display on the screen. And all this time battery indicator keeps blinking. Even after opening from suspend mode, screen flickers three times and then comes black screen.After  closing and opening the lid in fast speed,display comes back. If I do restart or hibernate then also, laptop doesn't start.
On using external display, it doesn't show anything.

I am very much worried. I think this can be a motherboard issue. Also the screen flickers on starting sometimes. Can anyone help me solve this issue,please?

Comment: So it turns on but the screen doesn't show anything?  Can you turn brightness more?

Comment: Sometimes the screen is blank and sometimes it is black. I have tried to increase brightness. On black screen brightness increases but still it is black

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, after turning on the laptop HP logo used to show up and then its black, I know that the grub menu is there as it beeps and I use my arrow keys to navigate to whatever I want (linux/win). Btw its of no use because the screen is still black.

I opened my laptop and reinserted the SSD and both the RAM's. It solved the whole screen not coming issue.

Comment: Was your battery indicator blinking?

Comment: No for me it didn't blink

Answer (score 0):

After around 8 and a half months I found the solution to this. The problem was due to 30 pin display cable. This display cable was also not available in market on searching but after around 1.5 months I found it and now the laptop works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).